# Question from the GMAT test

Tags: grammar

From the GMAT test

> *The use of lie detectors is based on the assumption that lying produces emotional reactions in an individual* _______________________________
>
> **A**. *that, in turn, create unconscious physiological responses*
>
> **B**. *that create unconscious physiological responses in turn*
>
> **C.** *creating, in turn, unconscious physiological responses*
>
> **D.** *to create, in turn, physiological responses that are unconscious*
>
> **E.** *who creates unconscious physiological responses in turn*

---

The correct answer is supposed to be **A**.

Can you please explain to me why **C** is not possible? The meanings of answers **A** and **C** seem to be identical to me and I am not able to find in answer **C** any grammatical problem.

Comment: This is a difficult question. I wouldn't know how to answer this one.

Comment: Because of the "rule" about dangling participles. This "rule" would say that in C, the individual, and not the emotional reactions, creates the unconscious physiological reactions. This "rule" is completely specious, but test setters believe it and expect you to know it.

Comment: I don't rate this question (the GMAT one, not the request for clarification here on ELU) very highly, but I imagine the test setter is obsessing about ambiguity regarding the idiomatic ***in turn*** (usually meaning *one after another*, but here the intended sense is *as a [logical] consequence*). Only #A explicitly establishes this sense by placing ***in turn*** immediately before the action it applies to (the verb ***create***).

Comment: @Peter: I'm not convinced. What I see is that #C could be wrongly interpreted as meaning that multiple responses are created *in turn = consecutively*, where the intended sense is that *the [logical, inevitable] consequence of [producing] the emotional reactions* is the creation of those unconscious responses.

Comment: I think that the reason C isn't acceptable to the test creator/grader is that the sentence doesn't include a comma after _individual_. If it did include a comma there, I'm pretty sure that the preferred answer would flip, and the grader would consider C correct and A incorrect.

Comment: This sort of test comes from obsessive individuals who have lost sight of the realities of language and are engaged in disappearing up their own subordinate clauses.

Comment: I agree with Sven Yargs. It's the missing comma.

Comment: Shouldn't it be WHICH instead of THAT due to the pluralness of "emotional reactions" ??

Comment: @JoeBlow: No, there's no rule whereby singular *that* alternates with plural *which*. The plural of "the book that we read together" is "the books that we read together"; the plural of "her book, which we read together" is "her books, which we read together".

Comment: C is devious because the question breaks right where the mind inserts a pause that makes everything except the punctuation just fine.  But I would still prefer A.

Comment: Ruakh - fair enough, **thanks**, I bow to your knowledge on that item.  (But I do disagree with your answer, as per comments!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With (C), we get this sentence:

> The use of lie detectors is based on the assumption that lying produces emotional reactions in an individual creating, in turn, unconscious physiological responses.

Let's set aside the "The use of lie detectors is based on the assumption that" part, and just focus on the declarative content clause at the end:

> Lying produces emotional reactions in an individual creating, in turn, unconscious physiological responses.

The biggest problem with this sentence is that a comma is missing between "individual" and "creating": without that comma, "an individual creating […]" means "an individual who creates […]", which makes no sense at all.

Fixing that, we get:

> Lying produces emotional reactions in an individual, creating, in turn, unconscious physiological responses.

This sentence is not terrible, but it's still not completely right.

What the sentence is trying to say is: {lying} → {emotional reactions in an individual} → {unconscious physiological responses}. (The "in turn" is intended to convey this sequence: each step causes the step after it.) But this latest version instead has "creating, in turn, unconscious physiological responses" modifying all of "lying produces emotional reactions in an individual"; it says: {{lying} → {emotional reactions in an individual}} → {unconscious physiological responses}.

This may seem subtle — after all, the overall meaning is clear even despite the slight misphrasing — but (A) is definitely the most precise way to express what is meant.

Comment: I really don't agree with this. "What the sentence is saying is", in fact, "Detectors are based on one assumption." There is then a **long addendum** describing that assumption.

Comment: In your second sentence in a gray box: it's just plain wrong: you have "emotional reactions" ... "creating".  It would have to be "emotional reactions" ... "which create". Your sentence is like: "Red is a color creating anger."  That's wrong.  "Red is a color which creates anger."

Comment: @JoeBlow: Re: "sentence": fair enough -- I'll fix that wording -- but you are totally focusing on the wrong thing. (I think you haven't actually understood this answer.)

Comment: No, I think you're over-thinking the subtlety of GMAT test-setters  :-)

Comment: @JoeBlow: Your second comment really makes no sense. Do you think that "he walked out, leaving her alone with her thoughts" is "just plain wrong" because it has "he ... leaving"? Do you think that it should instead be "he walked out who leaves her alone with her thoughts"?

Comment: Hi Ruakh.  The example I gave ("Red..." etc) makes perfect sense. In your example: **"He walked out, leaving ..."** the final clause must make sense for "leaving".  So, all of the following are fine.  **He walked out, leaving nothing. He walked out, leaving the cat alone. He walked out, leaving the house very secure.**  However (exactly like my "Red" example) the following examples make no sense: **He walked out, leaving large cat. He walked out, leaving everything is great. He walked out, leaving think positive.**

Comment: @JoeBlow: OK, good, so you do understand. Now apply that understanding to the actual question, and you'll be golden. :-)

Comment: And what is wrong with the sentence "Red is a color creating anger"?

Comment: @JoeBlow Red is a color that creates anger

Answer (score 0):

The broad explanation, or, let us say, the beginning of any explanation is this:

The subject "at hand" is ..

## "emotional reactions"

the phrase A/B/C/D/E must "work correctly" **with that phrase**.

**From there, on that basis**, you would have to apply precisely what Peter says, and I need only quote Peter verbatim:

> "Because of the "rule" about dangling participles. This "rule" would
> say that in C, the individual, and not the emotional reactions,
> creates the unconscious physiological reactions. This "rule" is
> completely specious, but test setters believe it and expect you to
> know it."

Note that I say the "subject at hand" is emotional reactions. But it's nested inside the subject "assumption".

## So to *really* begin with ...

you have to treat everything after "assumption that" ... as a, uh, sentence fragment which **works correctly** in **describing an assumption**.

Hence consider:

> The use of lie detectors is based on one assumption. We'll call that
> Assumption X. What is Assumption X? Assumption X is the assumption
> that: _____

From there it's fairly obvious that "A" is the only one that works, for various reasons (try it).

---

*Note however, I think it should be 'which' rather than 'that' since 'emotional reactions' is plural.  But, I'm not sure about that.*